# How to access Pages document when I forgot the password for it?

Tags: icloud, pages

Sometimes I set up a password for my Pages document, and I forget it. Is there a way to access the document without a password or recover password back anyway?

Comment: I had a word doc with a password - opened in pages which totally ingored the password !!! So, try making a copy and try every other program to open it - not apple ones but any text type editors : you never know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. What would be the purpose of a password if you didn't need it to open the document.

Next time, write down the password if you forget easily.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. As far as I know there is absolutely no way to open a locked document without the password. I have searched many different websites and the all came up with this same answer.  And I hope for your sake that those documents aren't to important. But don't give up and delete your documents just yet, because maybe if you look in the right places you'll find a way. I recommend that next time you lock a document you add a hint you know will help you.(I didn't do that and that's where my problem started.) I'll come back and let you know if I find a better answer. I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a new document
2. Go to original document
3. Go to edit and select all
4. They go back to the new document and paste

Now, write down the new password or make it something that you can remember
Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Pages, as any iWork documents with password protection, are AES-128 encrypted. As of today, there is no easy way around it.

The following describes the hard way: Attacking the password with brute force. It can only help you, if the **password** is somewhat **weak**:

- Short password (~ less than 6 characters)
- You know which characters/words are used in the password (and they are not many)
- Common words of your language

Get a copy of "John the Ripper" (jumbo version):

```
git clone https://github.com/openwall/john.git
```

Build JtR:

```
cd john/src
./configure
make
```

The jumbo-version of JtR provides a tool to convert an iWork (pages) file into a problem JtR can tackle.

```
john/run/iwork2john.py encrypted.pages > encryped.hash
```

Now, your copy of JtR can try to brute force the password. For a dictionary attack, try the rockyou.txt dictionary of commonly used passwords:

```
wget https://www.scrapmaker.com/data/wordlists/dictionaries/rockyou.txt

./john/src/john --wordlist='rockyou.txt' encryped.hash
```

John the Ripper will work on all available threads to try out all passwords. If you know anything about the password, you can run JtR with a **mask**.

For example: You know that the PW starts with an uppercase letter and continues with 5 lowercase letters:

```
./john/src/john --mask='?u?l?l?l?l?l' encrypted.hash
```

For more brute-force mechanisms and techniques, please check the [documentation](https://www.openwall.com/john/doc/)

Please note that the longer the password is, the time to brute-force it grows by an order of magnitude. JtR will give you an estimation on when it's going to be finished. If you need more computational power, there are [cloud-services](https://www.openwall.com/john/cloud/) which can help you.